# EF6 Not saving changes to Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-6

After following this tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5251396/Use-Azure-Functions-to-process-a-CSV-File-and-impo

I have run into an issue. My code executes perfectly, but the data is not saved to the db. I have tried my UAT database on azure as well as my local instance.

Here is the code I have:

```
namespace func
{
    public class Function3
    {
        [FunctionName("storagetrigger")]
        public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("filedump/{name}", Connection = "StorageConn")] Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
            if (myBlob.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(myBlob))
                {
                    var lineNumber = 1;
                    var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        await ProcessLine(name, line, lineNumber, log);
                        line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                        lineNumber++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task ProcessLine(string name, string line, int lineNumber, ILogger log)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                log.LogWarning($"{name}: {lineNumber} is empty.");
                return;
            }

            var parts = line.Split('|');
            if (parts.Length != 14)
            {
                log.LogError($"{name}: {lineNumber} invalid data: {line}.");
                return;
            }

            PackDataModel(parts ,out var item); //Packs data into my model

            using (var context = new PartContext())
            {
                context.Parts.Add(item);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                log.LogInformation($"{name}: {lineNumber} inserted task: \"{item.PartDescription}\" with id: {item.PartNumber}.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My DB context:

```
    internal class PartContext : DbContext
    {
        public PartContext() : base("PartsContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Part> Parts { get; set; }
    }
```

The local conn string I used:

```
"PartsContext": "Provider=MySQL Provider;server=localhost;User Id=MyID;password=myPassword;database=mydb;"
```

Another conn string I tried:

```
"PartsContext": "Server=.;Database=sqldb-filedump-mpw-uat;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

Comment: Your connection string's name is "PartsContext" but it is different from your base("PartContext")

Comment: Ahhh missed that, but unfortunately did not fix it :( I tried a new conn string: ```"PartsContext": "Server=.;Database=sqldb-filedump-mpw-uat;Trusted_Connection=True;" ``` but still no changes in the db

Comment: Have you checked the logs or inserted a breakpoint on the line where you save changes?

Comment: Right after ` context.Parts.Add(item);` add `var conn = context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;` then use a breakpoint to verify that this connection string actually matches the one you are expecting. The typical culprit is when putting the data access in an assembly and updating the connection string within an App.config or an area sub web.config file for MVC where at runtime the application pulls the connection string from the main app / web.config file.

Comment: So I managed to find it thanks to Steve, the conn string never pulled through directly from the settings. I just needed to change it to base(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PartsContext")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the issue seems to have been that you cant pass a name to base as the tutorial displayed.

I resolved it by using:

```
public PartContext() : base(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PartsContext")
```